# EventListener on parent page - Block scrolling through iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I'm facing some problems with my iFrame event listener on jQuery, the part of the code I need to fix is this one:

```js
function BlockScrollbar(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

$.fancybox.open({
  src: $(this).find("a:first").attr("href"),
  type: 'iframe',
  infobar: false,
  toolbar: false,
  beforeShow: function() {
    document.addEventListener('mousewheel', BlockScrollbar, {
      passive: false
    });
  },
  afterClose: function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousewheel', BlockScrollbar);
  }
});
```

I disabled the scrollwheel on the whole page and during the loading of my iFrame, the problem is that for some reason I can still scroll the page behind if I do it through the iFrame.

My goal would be to completely disable the scrolling while an iFrame is opened. Do you have any idea why it's not 100% working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm opening an iFrame the whole document was able to scroll though it cause the event listener were based on the first page. I fixed this behavior by adding a ready(function() on the page oppened by the iFrame.

```
function BlockScrollbar(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}


(function($) 
{
$(document).ready(function() 

{
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', BlockScrollbar, {passive: false});
}
);
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try these?

```
 function BlockScrollbar() {
 window.parent.document.$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: I just tried them, the page is still working in the same way, scrolling blocked everywhere but not through the iFrame

Comment: I have editted my answer, can u try those?

Comment: I'm sorry but still not working, it seems that the iFrame scrolling isn't being influenced by the code, since the background body is being blocked as intended